# ImportError: Python pygame module

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am using Python 3.4.2 and am working on a python file named game.py which starts off like...

```
import os, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
from libs.hexagon import *
```

The problem is that when I run it in the Python 3.4.2 shell, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\docs\game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, pygame, math
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I tried searching this online and saw stuff like installing modules,, etc.

Can somebody make it clear what I really need to do.

Thanks, Olivia

Comment: Do you have Pygame installed?

Comment: Pygame is **not** Python. Pygame is a *package* for Python.

Comment: You may have problems  installing pygame for python3 on windows

Answer (score 0):

Like u/TigerhawkT3 noted, you need to install Pygame on your system. Pygame doesn't come with installing Python.

Here is a link to the Pygame site where you can find out [how to install Pygame](http://pygame.org/download.shtml). Please install Pygame since it appears you may not have done so yet. Then, attempt to run the program again.

Comment: No. It doesn't make sense to install a module into a file. If you want it to run on a computer without Pygame, you have to use a packager like py2exe or cx_freeze.

Comment: Olivia, I mean your computer so your Windows PC or Mac computer for instance. As to your other question, I don't have that answer and that's probably a second StackOverflow post on its own. First, if you have the ability to install programs on your computer, please install PyGame by following the instructions and re-run the .py file after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Pygame. If you're on Windows, get the necessary wheel file from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). If you're on another OS, you'll have to Google up an appropriate version. Once you've gotten the file, install it by opening a command prompt and typing:

```
pip install C:\full_file_path_here\full_file_name_here
```

replacing the path and filename as necessary.